# Spring security in Grails 4 is not differentiating roles

Tags: security

I am in trouble in Grails 4, while trying to use Spring Security.

I have initiated a project with the rest api profile e been trying to implement the Spring Security Roles to differentiate access to each of my controller methods. The problem is that when I request without a token ou with an invalid token (for instance, if I change some character randomly) I receive a forbidden. That's ok.

But, I have to roles: USER and USER_ADMIN. here is my problem. Even if I annotate for a specific role, never mind. If I request with a token valid for the other role, the request is succesfully completed but, I the correct was to receive an unauthorized (401 or 403). I have no idea where the problem is, that's why I am here asking for help. Thanks.

**my controller**

```
class ApiController {

@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
def getDocument() {
    def doc = DocumentPropertiesValidationService.getDecryptedDocument(params.id);

    if (doc) {
        render doc as JSON
    } else {
        Map response = ["status": "Document " + params.id + " not found"];
        render response as JSON
    }
}
```

**APPLICATION.GROOVY**

```
  grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        [pattern: '/api/document/**',    access: ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']],
        [pattern: '/api/**',             access: ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']],
        [pattern: '/**',                 access: ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']]
    ]


    grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.useBearerToken = true
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.enableAnonymousAccess = false


    grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials  = true
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.jwt.useSignedJwt = true
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.jwt.secret = 'mySecret'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.jwt.expiration = 60 * 60 * 24

    grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Annotation"


    grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
            [pattern: '/api/document/**', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS'], //,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'],
            [pattern: '/api/**', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'],
            //[pattern: '/api/**', filters:'JOINED_FILTERS'],//,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter'],
            //[pattern: '/api/document/**', filters:'JOINED_FILTERS'],//,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter'],
            [pattern: '/**', filters:'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter']//,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter']
    ]
```

**BUILD.GRADLE SPRING SECURITY DEPENDENCIES**

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:4.0.0.RC2'
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:3.0.0.RC1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this one, if I am reading your question correctly.  The documentation has not changed hasRole() to hasAuthority()
When I changed my annotation to

```
@Secured(value=["hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')"])
```

I got the expected behavior.